# When designing websites, what are my options for data storage?

Tags: database, data-storage

I am a website designer, and I design both sites and applications for the web. I use PHP.

I often find I have to store information, which needs to be accessed by the user after the browser is closed.

Up until now I have always used a database (MySQL to be precise) to store information, however sometimes, I feel that I am storing information that does not warrant database storage, mainly because the database does not travel with the application - it needs to be created separately.

Are there any other options for storing small amounts of data? Something simpler perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy a properties file or an XML file with the app to store things you don't feel are appropriate to a database.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlite.org/

It's still a database, just within a file. No(t much) setup required.

Answer (score 0):

Database is perfectly fine if you can differentiate users. Other storage mechanisms include cookies and [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) and ersatzdatabases like XML or plain-text files.

Comment: And don't forget SQLite: An SQL database which travels with the site like any other file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are using PHP, but some Web application frameworks for other languages such as [Happstack](http://happstack.com/index.html) (for Haskell) use an internal RAM based data storage serialized on the disk.

> Happstack's RAM cloud database
>   architecture provides you the speed
>   and predictability of RAM based
>   queries combined with the durability,
>   replication, and ACID properties of
>   traditional databases.

If you are interested, you can study the approach, I bet there are others.